# I am not sure if my proof that$(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$ using only the axioms of real numbers is correct

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, real-numbers, alternative-proof

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do this since I am manipulating both sides at the same time( since I am starting with what I'm supposed to prove). I'm pretty sure a correct proof is when you start with the left side and then show that it's equal to the right side, but in this case, I had no idea how to do this.
$(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$
$(x^{-1})^{-1}*x^{-1} = x*x^{-1}$ (Using the property of Replacement)
1 = 1                             ( Axiom of Multiplicative Inverse)

Is this proof valid ? and if by chance this proof is valid, is there a better way to prove this ?

Comment: You should never start with what you *hope* is true and use that to reach a tautology... you should do it in the other direction.  Start with a tautology and use that to prove what you want.

Comment: It is valid as long as you ensure that each line follows from the one _after_ it (since the final line is the one you know to be true). I usually represent this with a $\Leftarrow$ after each equation. Either that, or simply write the lines in the reverse order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just start with $x$ and proceed directly. $$x=1x=((x^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1})x=(x^{-1})^{-1}(x^{-1}x)= (x^{-1})^{-1}1=(x^{-1})^{-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\neq 0$.

Let us suppose there are two inverses of $x$, which we shall denote by $y$ and $z$.

Then one concludes they are equal. Indeed, one has:
\begin{align*}
y = y\cdot 1 = y(xz) = (yx)z = 1\cdot z = z
\end{align*}
which confirms its uniqueness.

Based on such result, we are now able to prove the desired claim. Indeed, one has:
\begin{align*}
xx^{-1} = 1 = x^{-1}(x^{-1})^{-1} = (x^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1} \Rightarrow x = (x^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense but why do I need to prove the uniqueness first? you didn't use this fact in your proof.

Comment: @user20194358 I applied the uniqueness of the inverse of $x^{-1}$ in order to conclude that $x = (x^{-1})^{-1}$.